# Dict comprehension from split str

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I'm trying to make a dict out this str:

```
a='ALLELEID=677660;CLNDISDB=MedGen:C0162671,OMIM:540000,Orphanet:ORPHA550,SNOMED_CT:39925003;CLNDN=Juvenile_myopathy,_encephalopathy,_lactic_acidosis_AND_stroke;CLNHGVS=NC_012920.1:m.15992A>T;CLNREVSTAT=criteria_provided,_single_submitter;CLNSIG=Likely_benign;CLNVC=single_nucleotide_variant;CLNVCSO=SO:0001483;GENEINFO=MT-TP:4571;ORIGIN=1'
```

This works:

```
d={}
for i in a.split(';'):
    key, val = i.split('=')
    d[key] = val
```

Why doesn't this work?

```
d={key: val for key, val in i.split('=') for i in a.split(';')}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have nested dictionary comprehensions (unlike nested list comprehensions). The following will work:

```
dict(item.split("=") for item in a.split(';'))
```

`dict()` can build a dictionary from a list of 2-element lists or tuples.

Comment: Thanks - thats super simple, love it!

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
d={i.split('=')[0]: i.split('=')[1] for i in a.split(';')}
```

The second loop isn't needed (even if you needed it it would be wrong, you would need to put the second loop after the first loop).

Answer (score 0):

To use list comprehensions here you should use:

```
{key: val for i in a.split(';'), for key, val in i.split('=')}
```

But even you changed your code to this, it won't work since this is wrong:

```
for key, val in i.split('=')
```

the results of `i.split('=')` is an 1d array where you can only iterate with one element.

So eventually, you will only need one level of list comprehension:

```
{i.split('=')[0]: i.split('=')[1] for i in a.split(';')}
```